# how to hide UIApplication Status bar in both Ios version 6.0 and 7.0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

i want to hide status bar hidden in both ios 6.0  and ios 7.0. 
please can you explain any common method which work in both ios version for ios.

please provide solution :-

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update In  Plist add these property.

```
Status bar is initially hidden = YES

View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

[image: Plist]

Programatically

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    } }

// add this too
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES; }
```

Comment: But in my Application requirement is following:              1) i have Status bar is initially hidden = NO and 
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO                       now i want to hidden status bar show by code . so now status bar is show in spacific screen but now in other screen status bar is hidden but one gape is appereing on top of the navigationbar    so please provide solution for that. how to remove blank gap of status bar from view controller.

Comment: please check your Xib size and check its having status bar is None
also if you need to hide it programatically add code in
Place one of these 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
 either in viewWillAppear:, viewWillLoad or viewDidAppear:

Comment: also check programatically